# How to add a Thunderbird addon globally?

Tags: software-installation, thunderbird

I have downloaded a Thunderbird extension as a`.xpi` file.

I know, I can install it in Thunderbird by going to

```
Tools
  -> Addons
     -> Install Add-on from file
```

However, I am using several Thunderbird profiles and I would have to do this for each of them.

How can I install this addon globally (presumably somewhere in `/usr/share/xul-ext`)? Do I have to unpack this `.xpi` extension file there?

Comment: I think if you copy xpi file in /usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/ or /usr/lib64/thunderbird/extensions/ it will be available for all users, however no automatic updates are performed.

Comment: there are some extensions in `/usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/` but not as .xpi` files. They have names such as: `{972aa4c6-7e44-0174-a132-3208198ae6fd}`. I don't think I can just copy the `.xpi` file there.

Comment: Those shoul be extracted extensions. See in you ~./thunderbird/extensions there should have xpi and extracted if I want to be global I copy either xpi or folder {id} in /isr/lib64/thunderbird/extensions, because for some extenseions I have only xpi

Comment: See if [global installation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions) section helps, especially _uncompress the .xpi file yourself (as a ZIP file) to an appropriately named (extension's ID) folder_.

Answer (score 4):

Seemingly, the extension dir has a different location on different unices. On Ubuntu, it is `/usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions`. This answer keeps your dir of `/usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/`

1. unzip the xpi file (it is a zip)

   ```
   unzip addon.xpi
   ```
2. retrieve the add-on id from the `install.rdf` file:

   ```
   ID=$(grep em:id install.rdf  | head -1 | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -d '<' -f 1)
   ```
3. create directory of id-name under `extensions`:

   ```
   mkdir /usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/$ID
   ```
4. move the unzipped files

   ```
   mv $(ls | grep -v addon.xpi)) /usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/$ID
   ```

Be aware that these are not auto-updated. The question (by me) at [update-global-firefox-addons-automatically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220806/update-global-firefox-addons-automatically) is waiting ...

EDIT: with the advent of webextensions, getting the ID is a bit harder. Try the following script

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then echo 'needs to run as root'; exit; fi
D=$(mktemp -d)
unzip $1 -d $D
[ -f $D/manifest.json ] && ADDON_ID=$(openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in $D/META-INF/mozilla.rsa | grep -A 1 commonName | grep -E '{|@' | cut -d ':' -f 4)
[ -f $D/install.rdf ] && ADDON_ID=$(grep "em:id" $D/install.rdf  | head -1 | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1)
if [ x$ADDON_ID == x ]; then
    echo "ADDON_ID retrieval failed"
    exit
else
    echo ID: $ADDON_ID
fi
chmod 755 $D
chmod -R a+r $D
rm -rf /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/$ADDON_ID
mv $D /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/$ADDON_ID
```