# Update global firefox addons automatically

Tags: upgrade, firefox, thunderbird

You can install firefox (or thunderbird) addons for all users of the same system. (See [how-to-add-a-thunderbird-addon-globally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190258/how-to-add-a-thunderbird-addon-globally/220804#220804), same applies for firefox)

How can these be automatically updated?

Comment: When you open Firefox and go too `about:addons`, does it offer to updates the addons? It may be able to update with by installing local user copy of the addon.

Comment: @Wilf: no, it does not do so by default

Answer (score 1):

They can't, that's the downside of this method.

(Except if they're isntalled through your distribution's package manager and there's an update through those...)

Comment: How about a manual update process (`wget` etc. via `cron`)? Is that possible?

Comment: You could do that, yes. The point is that you can't do it from within firefox.

Comment: Yes, but "from within firefox", installing an addon globally has never worked, either. YMMV

Comment: It probably would be possible to make a script to do the update - alternatively you could do a packaged version ([rpm example](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/mozilla-noscript/), [deb example](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xul-ext-websites-integration)), update the packaged version, and then include it in a repo/ppa/copr/whatever to update it.